# Python Backslash JSON Escaping issue - adding unwanted double backslash \\

Tags: python, escaping, backslash

For a Locust performance test, I have some JSON that I need to send to an API.
I need to randomise some of the data in the JSON before sending it but annoyingly the JSON has some escaped double quotes that are scuppering things as JSON.loads is adding an extra \ to escape the backslash. Is there a way to stop this?

Setup - simplified for the sake of the question:

1. I have 0.json with content like this:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "question": "Do you prefer ${option_a} or ${option_b}",
    "info": "here is some <b class=\"indented-content\">extra info</b>"
}
```

2. I have a dict of replacement text:

```py
replacement_data = dict(
    option_a="bacon",
    option_b="eggs"
)
```

3. I then use the following to read in the JSON, replace the items as needed and load it as json ready to send to the API

```py
from string import Template
def generate_data():
    file = open('0.json')
    file_str = Template(file.read())
    data = json.loads(file_str.substitute(replacement_data))
return data
```

The problem is that if I print the resulting data to debug it, it looks like this:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "question": "Do you prefer bacon or eggs",
    "info": "here is some <b class=\\"indented-content\\">extra info</b>"
}
```

i.e. it's escaped the backslashes. This then gives me a 400 error when sending to the API as it is not formatted correctly.

I know it's unusual to have this situation, but is there a way to get it to replace the data and load it but not add in the extra backslashes please?

I have tried reading in the file after and doing a find and replace on double \ to , but this didn't work.

I've also tried changing the JSON to unicode, but that didn't work either... i.e.

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "question": "Do you prefer ${option_a} or ${option_b}",
    "info": "here is some <b class=\u00sc\u0022indented-content\u005c\u0022>extra info</b>"
}
```

**Info**
I know that proper JSON should not contain the backslash and that's why it gets removed. I agree with the many comments saying this, but that's not helpful to my question as if it's not there, the server rejects the file.

I didn't code the server side, I am merely trying to automate some tests on it so *please don't shoot the messenger*.

If anyone know how to get it so that the 2 individual single backslashes are preserved, please let me know (NB They are used to escape the " on the server side, so if they are missing, it fails).

Comment: Thou shalt not use string operations on JSON! `load()` it, modify it and `dump()` it again.

Comment: Sorry, missing , was a typo, corrected now.

Also, I agree, it shouldn't be in the JSON Klaus. D, but unfortunately that's the data that the API is expecting and it's how it was developed long before I came to test it so I can't change it... I am trying to find a way to work with it but it's proving challenging.

Comment: You have to apply the templating to the string inside the JSON, not the whole JSON.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What's the value of `Template(file.read()).template`?

Comment: @MatthiasHuschle that's the un-merged JSON (i.e. without the strings being replaced) and it contains the correct \" 

If you setup the code as per my question, and you print(data) are you still seeing a single backslash?

Comment: @cuppatea3 `print(json.loads(file_str.substitute(replacement_data)))` gives `{'id': 1, 'question': 'Do you prefer bacon or eggs', 'info': 'here is some <b class"indented-content">extra info</b>'}` which is correct, as json.dumps or whatever you use should take care of escaping. (btw. `=` is missing after `class`)

Comment: @MatthiasHuschle you have indeed replicated my issue. You can see that your output has stripped the \'s before the "'s. I need to retain those for the API to accept the content. (oops, yes that missing = is a typo... corrected now)... so I am still stuck as I need to preserve the single backslashes (as they are used at the other end to escape the ")

Comment: No. The *value* the JSON expresses does _not_ contain any backslashes. After having parsed the JSON, **there should be no backslashes in there.** The backslashes only exist because there's a double quote in the double-quote delimited JSON string. After having parsed that to a Python string, that is irrelevant. When you dump this backslash-less value back to JSON, the backslash will return, because the JSON formatter will put it back to protect the quote.

Comment: `print(json.dumps(json.loads(file_str.substitute(replacement_data))))` correctly outputs `...<b class=\"indented-content\">...` as expected; valid JSON which expresses the string `...<b class="indented-content">...`.

Comment: I know that ordinarily there should not be a backslash there... but in my case it needs to be there or the server rejects the file. I 100% understand what people are saying re proper JSON should not contain it, but in this instance I need it to be there... hence why I have created this post to see if anyone has any workarounds to get it to remain as a single backslash. Thanks all.

Comment: Proper JSON must contain *one* backslash before any double quote. As yours does. The backslash must only be there **when it’s JSON.** Once you have decoded it from JSON, there will correctly be no backslash. The JSON en-/decoder handles the backslash, you do not need to do anything about it manually. We have no idea how you’re getting to *two* backslashes with your code, or how exactly you’re sending the final data to your server.